Decode data on the client
I am currently facing the following issue:
I encrypt data using PHP, specifically Laravel, as follows:
static function encrypt($data)
{
    $publicPath = base_path('public.key');
    $publicKey = file_get_contents($publicPath);
    $dataEncode = utf8_encode($data);

    if(openssl_public_encrypt($dataEncode, $encrypted, $publicKey, OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING)){
       return base64_encode($encrypted);
    }
    return false;
}

And I decrypt on the client side, specifically in ReactJS. But when decrypting, the following error occurred:
'Decryption failed: Error: Encryption block is invalid.'
This is my React decryption code:
const decryptData = (encryptedData) => {
    const privateKey = forge.pki.privateKeyFromPem(key);
    const encryptedBuffer = forge.util.decode64(encryptedData);
    console.log(encryptedBuffer)

    try {
        const decrypted = privateKey.decrypt(encryptedBuffer, 'RSAES-PKCS1-V1_5');
        return decrypted; // Decrypted data as a string
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Decryption failed:', err);
        return null;
    }
};

This code includes a key, which is a private PEM key and encryptedData is the encrypted data received from Laravel.

forge.util.decode64 converts Base 64 to PKCS#12. I'm not sure that that's what you really want. It looks like you just want a simple BASE 64 decode.

Quick word of advice though. Never expose your private key to the client/internet like this (unless it's the user's private key and stays client side).

Also, I'm not sure what the point of encrypting something like this that is going to be decrypted on the client (aside from specifically wanting to verify that the data can be trusted). If the data is transmitted over https with TLS 1.2 + then it should be protected in transmission and only available to the client anyway.

I cannot reproduce the issue. On my machine, a ciphertext generated with the PHP code can be successfully decrypted with the JavaScript code. Check your data, which is probably inconsistent (e.g. unrelated keys etc.), in the wrong format, etc. Post test data (incl. non-productive) key pair. Note that utf8_encode() is deprecated.
